# Compute pairw cosine similarity given a row id of a sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, similarity, metrics

I wanna compute the pairwise cosine similarity between one row of a sparse matrix and the rest of rows. (Why? : because each row is a vectorized product_title, and I want to extract similar products given an id value).

Previously, I have `df_cleaned` as a `<504x41732 sparse matrix>` (each row, a product title, and the columns is due the tokens).

I defined :

```
def pairw_cos(prod_idx):
    prod = df_cleaned[prod_idx]
    foll_idx = prod_idx + 1 #thats a trick to select the rest of rows on the following line
    candidates_matrix = scipy.sparse.vstack([df_cleaned[:prod_idx, :], df_cleaned[foll_idx:, :]])
    simil_cosine = {}

    for candidates_idx, single_candidate in candidates_matrix.iterrows():
        single_simil = cosine_similarity(prod,single_candidate)
        simil_cosine[candidates_idx] = single_simil
    return pd.Series(simil_cosine)
```

But that doesn't works (because iterrows method doesnt exists in sparse matrices). Then, I tried:

```
for row in candidates_matrix:
    for candidates_idx, single_candidate in row:
        single_simil = cosine_similarity(prod,single_candidate)
        simil_cosine[candidates_idx] = single_simil
```

And, when calling the function, I obtained:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-4c45754152cc> in <module>()
----> 1 pairw_cos2(2)

<ipython-input-52-12d55d3c35e5> in pairw_cos2(prod_idx)
      7 
      8     for row in candidates_matrix:
----> 9         for candidates_idx, single_candidate in row:
     10             single_simil = cosine_similarity(prod,single_candidate)
     11             simil_cosine[candidates_idx] = single_simil

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ask the same question, i finally solved that :

```
def pairwise_cosine(prod_idx):
    prod = df_cleaned[prod_idx]
    foll_idx = prod_idx + 1
    candidates_matrix = scipy.sparse.vstack([df_cleaned[:prod_idx, :], df_cleaned[foll_idx:, :]])
    simil_cosine = {}
    to_enumerate = []

    for row in candidates_matrix:
        simil_per_row= []
        simil_per_row = cosine_similarity(row,prod)
        to_enumerate.append(simil_per_row)
    for index, row in enumerate(candidates_matrix):
        simil_cosine[index] = to_enumerate[index]
    return pd.Series(simil_cosine)
```